# Vitables or other HDF5 viewers on Windows?

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I was looking for a hdf5 viewer for windows and came across vitables. However, vitables requires sip, which has all kinds of install problems under Anaconda... another alternative would be HDFview, but that requires a full Java installation (I use Python).

Are there really no standalone HDF5 viewers or am I missing some important point here?!? Or is HDF5 out and e.g. HDFS in? :P

Comment: None that I know of :s

Comment: ViTables is included in the Pythonxy python distribution. works out of the box. I don't know if you can install it in parallel, but I very much enjoy working with it.

Comment: Update: conda install -c conda-forge vitables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was like you and got fed up. I decided to develope one myself for my rudimentary needs. It's a visualization tool in Python for pytables and I just released it. It's called WiTables:

https://github.com/QHedgeTech/witables

It works on windows as long as you can install a web server that works with wsgi.

Answer (score 2):

You can install https://anaconda.org/clinicalgraphics/vitables using

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/clinicalgraphics vitables
```

and then run `vitables` using:

```
python D:\Anaconda\Scripts\vitables
```

Comment: Update: conda install -c conda-forge vitables